# Is there a switch to disable trigraphs with clang?

Tags: c++, clang, trigraphs

I've got some (legacy) code that I'm building with clang for the first time. The code is something like:

```
sprintf(buf, "%s <%s ????>", p1, p2);
```

Clang gives the following warning (error with `-Werror`):

```
test.c:6:33: error: trigraph converted to '}' character [-Werror,-Wtrigraphs]
    sprintf(buf, "%s <%s ????>", p1, p2);
                           ^
```

Clearly the `??>` is not intended as a trigraph, so I want to disable trigraphs entirely (the source does not intentionally use them anywhere).

I have tried `-no-trigraphs` but that's not really an option:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-no-trigraphs'
```

I can turn off the trigraphs warning with `-Wno-trigraphs` but I don't want the trigraph conversion to actually take place at all.

NOTE: Trigraphs were enabled as an unintended side effect of using `-std=c89`.

Comment: Ouch! GCC has a sensible policy of ignoring trigraphs, even in strict compliance mode, unless you hold its hands to the fire with `-trigraphs`.  Time to break out `sed`?  Or an equivalent.

Comment: Actually GCC's strict compliance modes (`-std=c89`, `-std=c99`, etc) do turn on trigraph conversion.

Comment: And if anyone is wondering WTH is a trigraph. [Here's the pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do)...

Comment: They do?  [_...pause...conduct experiment..._]  Oh, yes, apparently they do.  Oh, that's good; it saves me doing a search in my source code, since the stuff works.  I'll add `-Wtrigraphs` to my uber-fussy compilation options for a while, or go grepping, I suppose, but I've not seen any problems so it is unlikely to afflict me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `-Wtrigraphs` is on by default as long as you *don't* request trigraph conversion (explicitly or implicitly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using gnu* mode - "Trigraphs default to being off in gnu* modes; they can be enabled by the -trigraphs option." (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c_modes for other differences and command line switch)

Comment: Ah, that was it! I was using `-std=c89`, but with `-std=gnu89` I get the message `error: trigraph ignored [-Werror,-Wtrigraphs]` which I can disable with `-Wno-trigraphs`.

Comment: Is there a way to disable trigraphs without also enabling gnu extensions?

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't see an obvious way to disable trigraphs (rather than the trigraphs warning). Probably the easiest way to fix this code is to change it to:

```
sprintf(buf, "%s <%s ????"">", p1, p2);
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable option. Out of millions of lines of source, `??>` only occurs four times.

Comment: `"...???\?>"` should also work.  Put the backslash between the two question marks of the trigraph itself.

Comment: Since trigraphs can appear anywhere, maybe `sed "s/??\([-<>()\/=#']\)/?\\?\1/g"` to convert any trigraph into a safe sequence.  On the other hand, outside of a string, maybe the trigraph would be best converted to its standard form?  It gets a bit tricky to decide what's best.  (Just for once, my `sed` script uses double quotes around the pattern, because there is a single quote in the pattern.)