# Trigraph characters

Tags: c, trigraphs

```
c99 standard  5.2.1.1 Trigraph sequences
```

2 EXAMPLE The following source line

```
printf("Eh???/n");
```

becomes (after replacement of the trigraph sequence ??/)

```
printf("Eh?\n");
```

It's saying that it will replace the trigraph sequence, but it's not .

It's printing `"Eh???/n"`

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What compiler is this? Did you enable trigraphs? I believe they're disabled by default in a lot of compilers nowadays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigraphs are disabled by default in gcc. If you are using gcc then compile with `-trigraphs` to enable trigraphs:

```
gcc -trigraphs source.c
```

Answer (score 1):

The `??/` in the printf is a trigraph character which is a part of C's preprocessor.

If you enable trigraph by using `gcc -trigraphs source.c`, it will convert `??/` into `\`. Your code will look like this:

`printf("Eh???/n"); // Before enable trigraph`

`printf("Eh?\n"); // After enable trigraph`

You can visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C for more information.

Possible duplicate of [What does the C ??!??! operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825055/8275080)